# How to Upload file using file-model directive in AngularJS and nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

Hello I am working with file upload concept In MEAN Stack.But file is not

uploading.I used the file-model directives.

here is my **angular controller.js**  file function.

```
 app.controller("usercontroller",function($scope,$http, $localStorage,$location,flash){

$scope.adduser = function(message) 
    {


         $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:'api/adduser',
            data:{name:$scope.name,email:$scope.email,password:$scope.password,address:$scope.address,sex:$scope.sex,file:$scope.file},
                transformRequest:angular.identity,
                headers:{'Content-Type':undefined }
             }).then(function successCallback(response) {
              if(response.data.error){
                    $scope.error = response.data.error;

              }else{
                    $scope.Blog=response.data;
                    $localStorage.dd=$scope.Blog;
                    flash.setMessage(message);
                    $location.path('/allusers');
              }
              //console.log(response);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
               alert("data is not comming here");
            });
    }

});
```

I used the directive same file controller.js above to the controller.

```
app.directive('fileModel', function ($parse) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
          var modelSetter = model.assign;

          element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
              if (attrs.multiple) {
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files);
              }
              else {
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
              }
            });
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

input type of file is

```
 <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Phone_no" class="col-sm-3">ImageUpload</label>
       <div class="col-sm-4 @if($errors->has('Phone_no')) has-error @endif">
       <input class="form-control input-sm" name="files" file-model="file" type="file" >
   </div>
 </div>
```

I used the storage function into the api file.
     var storage = multer.diskStorage({

```
    destination:function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,'../public/uploads/')
    },

    filename:function(req,file,cb){

        console.log('file',file);
        var c = mime.extension(file.mimetype);
        console.log(c);

        //debugger;

        cb(null,Date.now()+'.'+ mime.extension(file.mimetype));
    }
}); 

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

and then in **api.js** file

router.post('/adduser',userController.adduser);

Here is the **userController.js** file

```
module.exports.adduser = function (req, res)
{
    var user = new Usermodel();
    user.name = req.body.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.address = req.body.address;
    user.sex = req.body.sex;

    console.log(req.file.filename);

    user.save(function (err, data) {
        if (err)
        {
            //console.log(err);
            res.send(err);

        } else
        {
            //console.log("valueEnterd");
            res.send(data);
        }

    })
};
```

this line is giving error

**console.log(req.file.filename);**

and when I see the

```
console.log($scope.file);
```

in the angular controller.js file

the result is like

```
lastModified:1458666536337
lastModifiedDate:Tue Mar 22 2016 22:38:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
name:"shahzad Qureshi.jpg"
size:81107
type:"image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath:""
__proto__:File
```